# Whats the most efficient way to do array intersect with mysql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, intersect

Ok so I want to make a table that's something like this

```
id    values    
1     array1    
2     array2    
3     array3
```

Then I want to create a second table thats a product of the first table with itself where the values would be the intersection of values from both ids

So the second table would be like

```
id    values    
1,2   intersection of array1 and array2    
1,3   intersection of array1 and array3
2,3   intersection of array2 and array3
```

I have no idea how to do this because there is no array type. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you insist on using arrays, you're probably my going to have to use array serialization to store the info, then use a scripting language like PHP to manage the other portions of your code.

Comment: Why not use postgres which has array support.

Comment: Thanks. Postgres worked. My table has 5000 rows and the product took 30 minutes. Is there a good way to speed it up?